Positive integral solutions to ternary form $Ax^ky-Bxy^k=Cz^{k+1}$

Given any choice of integers $A,B,C,k\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $C,k>0$ and $A>B$, does the ternary form
$$Ax^ky-Bxy^k=Cz^{k+1},$$
have a solution in the positive integers?

Original question:
Given the expression $\sqrt[k+1]\frac{(cs^kt - bt^ks)}{(b-a)}$, where a,b,c $\in \mathbb{Z}$, k $\in \mathbb{N}$ are constants and a<b<c.   Also given that s,t $\in \mathbb{N}$ are parameters which can be changed, can we calibrate parameters s,t such that the expression value is a natural number?
I have no idea how to approach this problem. Any general theory or ideas using which the above problem can be tackled?
PS : I was working on a problem in Complexity Theory and the approach I took required me to evaluate such an expression.

For $s=t=0$ we obtain an integer, if zero is in $\Bbb N$ for you. Otherwise it may not work, take $c=-1$ and $b=1$. Then $cs^kt-bt^ks=-s^kt-t^ks<0$ for all $s,t,k\in \Bbb N$, so that the root is not a real number.

Hi thanks for your comment. I forgot to add in the question but there is a constraint of a<b<c. I’ve made the edit reflecting this.

Might as well replace $b-a$ with $a<b$ by just $d$ with $d>0$. And this seems way too broad.

@Servaes Right we can do that. Is it very broad though? Doesn't it boil down to checking whether there exists natural number solutions to the equation $dx^{k+1} = cs^kt - bt^ks$. I have no idea about such equations but I naively thought some theory behind the existence of solutions to such simple looking equations must be present. I introduced parameter t to this equation thinking it might help proving existence of solution. But we could also assume $t=1$ which results in a simpler looking equation of the form $dx^{k+1} = cs^k - bs$.

Of course more parameters and more variables make the question more broad, and more difficult to cover entirely. You have three parameters and two variables; eliminating one variable makes the problem much easier.

Also, what would you consider a sufficient answer? If there is a specific combination of $b$, $c$ and $d$ for which no such $s$ exists, would you consider your question answered?

@Servaes Yes that would be a sufficient answer.

I see now that I had misread the question yesterday; I thought that $k$ was also a parameter to be solved for. For fixed $b,c,d,k\in\Bbb{Z}$ the question is tractable, as examples without solutions can be constructed.

Please update the question to reflect your updates in the comments. Also make explicit whether you consider $0$ a natural number or not.

I'll answer your more restricted version of the question in the comments, where $t=1:

For any choice of integers $b,c,d,k\in\Bbb{Z}$ with $b<c$ and $d,k>0$, there are natural number $r,s\in\Bbb{N}$ such that
$$dr^{k+1}=s(cs^{k-1}-b).$$

I'll assume that you do not consider $0$ a natural number, as otherwise the answer is trivially 'yes' by taking $r=s=0$. Then the answer is 'no', as the following example shows:
Consider the specific choice $(b,c,d,k)=(1,8,1,2)$, so that $r,s\in\Bbb{N}$ must satisfy
$$r^3=s(8s-1).$$
The factors on the right hand side are coprime, so they are both perfect cubes, say $s=v^3$ and $8s-1=w^3$ for some integers $v$ and $w$. Then
$$1=8s-w^3=(2v)^3-w^3,$$
which implies that $v=0$ and $w=-1$, and so $s=0$. This shows that there are no integral solutions with $r,s\in\Bbb{N}$.

If we extend this example to the original question, of finding $r,s,t\in\Bbb{N}$ such that
$$dr^{k+1}=st(cs^{k-1}-bt^{k-1}),$$
then we see that in this case $r,s,t\in\Bbb{N}$ must satisfy
$$r^3=st(8s-t).$$
Without loss of generality we may assume that $s$ and $t$ are pairwise coprime. Then $s$ is also coprime to $8s-t$ and hence $s$ is a perfect cube, say $s=v^3$ for some positive integer $v$. Then also $r=uv$ for some integer $u$, and hence
$$u^3=t(8v^3-t),$$
where $v$ and $t$ are pairwise coprime, and so $\gcd(t,8v^3-t)$ either equals $1$ or $8$. Either way both factors on the right hand side are perfect cubes, so $t=x^3$ and $8v^3-t=y^3$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. Setting $z:=2v$ we find that
$$x^3+y^3=8v^3=z^3.$$
It is of course a classical result that this implies $xyz=0$. But then $r=0$ because
$$0=(xyz)^3=z^3\cdot x^3\cdot y^3=(2v)^3\cdot t\cdot(8v^3-t)=8st(8s-t)=8r^3.$$
This shows that there are no integral solutions with $r,s,t\in\Bbb{N}$.

Anyone care to explain the downvote?
